# Application hangs when trying to update wpf control from thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

My application is hanging at this line  `this.SFprogress.Value = 20;// this is a progress bar` and it's not raising any errors on visual studio.

I'm just trying to update the progress bar every time the event 'RecordPosted' is raised in the SalesForceExporter class. I'm new to threading an wpf and I'm pretty stumped with this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{ 
        var export = new SalesForceExporter(ItemsSource);
        export.RecordPosted += export_RecordPosted;
        Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(export.Export));
        oThread.IsBackground = true;
        oThread.Start();

 }
       void export_RecordPosted(object sender, RecordPostEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateProgress(e.RecordNumber, e.BatchSize);

    }

    private void UpdateProgress(int currntCount, int totalCount)
    {
        if (totalCount > 0)
        {
            //this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action<int,int>)((x,y) => { SFprogress.Value = 100d; }),currntCount,totalCount);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
            {
                this.SFprogress.Value = 20; // this is a progress bar
            }));
        }
```

Comment: Use BeginInvoke and try again.  If that doesn't help then you'll need to post a stack trace of the main thread.

Comment: Why don't you post it as an answer so i can choose it! That worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Because I don't know why it worked.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you anyways.